# Using insets with multi-panel plots (base plot)

Tags: r, plot

I want to add insets to both panels of my multi-panel plot. I set the margins and make the first plot, and then add the first inset:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1),cex = 0.5,lwd = 0.5,oma=c(3.2,2,1,1),mar = c(1,3,0,0))
plot(rev(1:10))    
par(fig = c(0.8,1,0.8,1), new = T)  
plot(1:10,col="red")
```

[image: Figure]

I now want to add the second big plot (which will go in the space below the first), and then a second inset in the top right hand corner of the second big plot. I also want to add a third inset somewhere in the left side of the second big plot (i.e. with different coordinates to the first two insets).

But because `par` has been altered, I can't get the second big plot to go in that space. I've tried using `par(op)` after the first insert, but that doesn't do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to plot the second main plot before you plot the insets, and reset `par` for the second inset:

```r
par(mfrow=c(2,1),cex = 0.5,lwd = 0.5,oma=c(3.2,2,1,1),mar = c(1,3,0,0))
plot(rev(1:10))    
plot(sample(1:10))
par(fig = c(0.8,1,0.8,1), new = TRUE)  
plot(1:10,col="red")
par(fig = c(0.8,1,0.3,0.5), new = TRUE)
plot(sample(1:10), col = "red")
```

[image]