# Multi-plots with insets - R basic plot function

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot multiple raster layers with insets using the basic plot function in R. Ideally, I can do this using the tmap package; however, I do not like the visual appeal of the plotting result with tmap. I want to use tim.color() function from the fields package for visualising the results hence my desire to use the basic raster.plot or plot function.

For demonstration purpose, I tried ploting the boundary of mainland Denmark twice with the Baltic island of Bornholm as an inset in each plot. I tried the code below but it did not work.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(Bdry$geometry)
par(new = TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.75, 1, 0.65, 1))
plot(Born$geometry,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", 
     lwd = 2,main = "Bornholm")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(Bdry$geometry)
par(new = TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.75, 1, 0.65, 1))
plot(Born$geometry,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", 
     lwd = 2,main = "Bornholm")
```

I got the output below.

[image]

However, I want to achieve something like the one below (plotted with tmap) using the basic plot function.

[image]

Code for reproducing the boundaries data below:

```
library(rgeoboundaries)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

DK <- gb_adm2("denmark", type = "sscgs")
plot(DK$geometry)

Born <- DK[DK$shapeName=="Bornholms Regionskommune",]

Main <- DK[DK$shapeName!="Bornholms Regionskommune",]

Main_r <- st_union(Main)
Bdry <- Main_r %>% st_sf %>% st_cast
class(Bdry)


plot(Bdry$geometry)
plot(Born$geometry)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution provided for multi plots in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177564/using-insets-with-multi-panel-plots-base-plot) and the advice from [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/subplot/) I was able to find a solution to my problem. I guess you have to play around with the par(fig=c(),new=T) option a bit to find the best plotting solution for your problem. After 1 hour of try and error, the code below gave the solution I was looking.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(Bdry$geometry)
plot(Bdry$geometry)
par(fig=c(0.28, 0.55, 0.6, 0.91), new = TRUE)
plot(Born$geometry,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", 
     lwd = 2,main = "Bornholm")
par(fig=c(0.79, 0.92, 0.58, 1), new = TRUE)
plot(Born$geometry,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", 
     lwd = 2,main = "Bornholm")
```

The result was

[image]